# Problem with Drag & Drop in Next.js 14 (dragging from component on page to component on template)

Tags: drag-and-drop, next.js13

I have a Next.js 14 app where I put a client-side rendered side-menu on a template, which then is shown on all pages. The menu has different folders on it. On one page, I have a table component (client side rendered).

What I'm trying to do, is implement drag&drop-functionality where I drag a row from the table to a folder in the side-menu.

I tried the packages react-dnd and react-beautiful-dnd for this, but it seems the draggable and droppable elements have to exist within the same context and that seems to not work when dragging from a component on a page to another component on a template.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could get D&D to work, given the page setup I outlined above?
Your help will be greatly appreciated!